# How to write sequential commands in batch file

Tags: batch-file, command-prompt

I want ot execute the following commands using batch file:

```
1.ftp 127.0.0.1 
2.USERNAME
3.PASSWORD 
4.put
5.D:\\zz.xml
6.mmm.xml
```

Each command is a sequence of the prev command

I want to move file from local to ftp server
I googled for that and I found that insert ; between commands  is the solution but itsn't correct for me

Please support me

Comment: I could not see how the c# tag was relevant; I removed it. If it was relevant, re add it, but explain in the question why this relates to c#.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1 is a command on the command prompt, but 2..6 are FTP commands.

I would put lines 2..6 in a file called `commands.txt` then redirect that file to stdin.

```
ftp 127.0.0.1 < commands.txt
```

**Edit:**
You could use `-s:commands.txt` instead of the `<` according to the ftp help.

> -s:filename     Specifies a text file containing FTP commands; the
>                     commands will automatically run after FTP starts.

Comment: what about sequential in FTP commands  It means <CRLF>
 between commands or what ??

Answer (score 0):

Use a `CRLF` between each command.

Answer (score 0):

I would rather use the expect command that allows you to script inputs according to outputs.
You can find some information here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect

You have an example on that page that describes exactly what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

@Albin Sunnanbo

Thanks for your reply

I solved the problem now from the following  tutorial
 http://www.dostips.com/DtTipsFtpBatchScript.php

I write the foillowing commnads in batch file:

```
FTP -v -i -s:commands.txt
```

then commands.txt contaisn the following commands

```
open 127.0.0.1 
UserName
Password
put
D:\\zz.xml
mmm.xml
```